# Which Testing framework will suit for Adobe CQ5 Project?

Tags: testing, aem

Which testing framework will suit for a Adobe CQ5 Project which is having some part of code in Java and some part of code in JSP for the CQ5 components?

Answer (score 1):

There are some details of testing of apache sling components on the [Sling Testing](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-testing-tools.html)  page, which will suit components within a CQ5 project

There are [remote tests](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-testing-tools.html#server-side-junit-tests-contributed-by-bundles) that can be deployed to a running CQ5 server and executed remotely (using curl for example)

There are also [integration tests](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-testing-tools.html#integration-tests-example) that create a sling launchpad instance and test against sling in-process.

Also, [Testing Sling Based Applications](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/testing-sling-based-applications.html) discusses approaches to testing the various types of components such as OSGI and provides the links to [mocks](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/testing-sling-based-applications.html#mock-classes-and-services) for common Sling classes (e.g. MockNode, MockProperty, MockResourceResolver).

Finally, if your components are just POJOs then you can just use plain old [JUnit](http://junit.org/) tests.  For testing the interaction with the web interface of your site/application you could use something like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)