# Sling Remote Junit Test Case

Tags: java, maven, junit, aem, sling

I'm trying to execute a JUnit test remotely on an Adobe AEM instance, using the JUnit Servlet. Post for reference: [Which Testing framework will suit for Adobe CQ5 Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336303/which-testing-framework-will-suit-for-adobe-cq5-project)

I've defined my testcase and was expecting to be able to see it at this URL

http://localhost:4502/system/sling/junit/

It does not show up though.

The test runs correctly with `mvn test`.

it's a very simple test case (junit3):

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
 public class mySampleTest extends TestCase {
    public void testSomething(){
        return;
    }
}
```

What do I need to do in order for the testcase to be available in the Sling remote JUnit test servlet?

Comment: I got a little bit further, I've noticed I had to add the Sling-Test-Regexp tag to my pom.

`<Sling-Test-Regexp>.*</Sling-Test-Regexp>`
Now it shows all the classes but not those that contain the tests.

Comment: Ok, it was indeed that. I set the Sling-Test-Regexp to .*Test and it shows only the classes ending with "Test" (as expected). Now I have to figure out why the classes in /src/main/test/ are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add annotation `@RunWith(SlingRemoteTestRunner.class)`. Also you should read about it [here](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-testing-tools.html#server-side-junit-tests-contributed-by-bundles) and you can see example [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/testing/samples/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/sling/testing/samples/integrationtests/serverside/ServerSideSampleTest.java)

Comment: Thanks for answering, the resources you've provided are known to me. AFAIK the RunWith Annotation is not neccessary - for example I'm able to run this test supplied by the sling integration tests: http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.junit.remote/1.0.8/org/apache/sling/junit/remote/exported/ExampleRemoteTest.java/?v=source

Comment: yes, this is another way of creating remote tests. But what about creating execution rule - SlingRemoteExecutionRule?

Comment: What about it? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Ok, I looked into example you posted and I found that tests in "org.apache.sling.testing.samples.sampletests" bundle are located under src/main and not under test/java what is logical, because test/java is not included into the bundle. So you can move your test into src/main and it will appear on sling junit servlet.

Comment: I've found that out :) My workaround was to configure the maven build in a way to put the compiled test class files in the same location as the others.